# How can I call `and_then` on a boxed Future?

Tags: rust

According to [Actix-Web Extractors](https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/) I can use `extract()` on the `HttpRequest` to convert the JSON-encoded body to a struct.

However `Json::<LoginData>::extract(&req);` returns a `Box<Future<...>>` which I cannot call `and_then` on.

How can I convert the `Box<Future<...>>` to just `Future<...>`?

Complete file:

```
extern crate actix_web;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate futures;
#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate json;

use actix_web::http::{Method};
use actix_web::{server, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Error, Json, FromRequest};

use futures::future::Future;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct LoginData {
    email: String,
    password: String,
}

fn login_handler(item: Json<LoginData>) -> Result<&'static str, Error> {
    Ok("hmmm")
}

fn login_handler2(req: HttpRequest) -> Box<Future<Item = HttpResponse, Error = Error>> {
    let info = Json::<LoginData>::extract(&req);
    info.and_then(|f| { f })
}

fn main() {
    server::new(
        || App::new()
            .route("/login", Method::POST, login_handler))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap()
        .run();
}
```

Error:

```
Compiling hello_world v0.1.0 (file:///Users/stavros/projects/test-rust/hello_world_so/hello_world)
error: the `and_then` method cannot be invoked on a trait object
  --> src/main.rs:25:10
   |
25 |     info.and_then(|f| { f })
   |          ^^^^^^^^
help: another candidate was found in the following trait, perhaps add a `use` for it:
   |
8  | use futures::future::Future;
   |

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `hello_world`.
```

My Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["docker"]

[dependencies]
actix-web = "0.6.10"
env_logger = "0.5.10"
futures = "0.2.1"
mysql = "13.1.0"
serde = "1.0.66"
serde_derive = "1.0.66"
serde_json = "1.0.20"
tokio = "0.1"
json = "*"
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] of the problem, including which definitions were imported into the code. It is also worth explaining what happens when you follow exactly what was proposed in that error message.

Comment: Same error. `use futures::future::Future;` is already there. I am stupid when it comes to Rust, but not *that* stupid to not be able to follow compiler suggestions :D

Comment: It might be worth also including the installed dependencies' versions.

Comment: Try setting `futures = "0.1"`.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423). You have both futures 0.1 and 0.2 present. If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Where do I have "futures 0.1"?

Comment: As shown in the duplicate question, actix-web pulls in actix which pulls in futures 0.1.

Comment: I see. Yeah looks like the same issue.