# Reading Rusoto S3 StreamingBody into something that Brotli can decompress

Tags: amazon-s3, rust, future, brotli, rusoto

Version 0.32 of [rusuto_s3](https://crates.io/crates/rusoto_s3)'s [StreamingBody](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_s3/struct.StreamingBody.html), which is returned when requesting a file from AWS S3, does not implement Read anymore.

Up to this version, `brotli::BrotliDecompress(&mut &*would_like_to_pass_this, &mut contents);` was the way I would get the data out from S3 and into contents.
Now this leads to this error message:

> error[E0614]: type `rusoto_s3::StreamingBody` cannot be dereferenced

An adjustment to `brotli::BrotliDecompress(&mut would_like_to_pass_this, &mut contents);` makes the complainer complain with:

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `rusoto_s3::StreamingBody::std::io::Read` is not satisfied
>
> the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `rusoto_s3::StreamingBody`

which is required by `brotli::BrotliDecompress`.

Because StreamingBody should implement Stream according to the documentation, I have tried to collect to a Vec using `let bytes = body.concat2().wait().unwrap();`.

However, this fails:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `concat2` found for type `rusoto_s3::StreamingBody` in the current scope                
  --> src/ingest/mod.rs:64:34
   |
64 |                 let bytes = body.concat2().wait().unwrap();                                                      
   |                                  ^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope                                                
   = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:                           
           candidate #1: `use futures::stream::Stream;`
```

As you can see in the full code example, the suggestion has been added with no different result.

```
use std::io::Cursor;

use futures::stream::Stream;
use rusoto_core::Region;
use rusoto_s3::{GetObjectRequest, S3, S3Client, StreamingBody};
use serde_json;

pub fn load_data_from_s3(folder_name: String) -> CustomObject {
    let client = S3Client::simple(Region::UsWest2);

    let mut custom_object = CustomObject::empty();

    // following a list of keys (~filenames) for S3
    ["key_name1", "key_name2"].iter().for_each(|key_name| {
        let request = GetObjectRequest {
            bucket: ("bigger_bucket/".to_owned() + &folder_name).to_string(),
            key: key_name.to_string(),
            ..Default::default()
        };
        if let Ok(file) = client.get_object(&request).sync() {
            // Calculate the content size by getting the current file size
            // multiplied by a factor of 3 for the decompression
            let initial_contents_size = match file.content_length {
                Some(data) => 3 * data as usize,
                _ => 0,
            };
            let mut contents = Cursor::new(Vec::with_capacity(initial_contents_size));

            /*
             *
             * Start of the problem area
             *
             */
            // BrotliDecompress needs to act on something with the Read trait implemented,
            // which isn't the case with StreamingBody anylonger
            let would_like_to_pass_this = file.body.unwrap();
            // trying to get a Vec<u8> here
            let bytes = would_like_to_pass_this.concat2().wait().unwrap();
            brotli::BrotliDecompress(&mut &*bytes, &mut contents);
            /*
             *
             * End of the problem area
             *
             */    

            // below code is for more context
            // Reset the cursor to the beginning so we can read the decompressed data
            contents.set_position(0);

            match *key_name {
                "key_name1" => custom_object
                    .do_stuff_with_key_name1_content(serde_json::from_reader(contents).unwrap()),
                "key_name2" => custom_object
                    .do_stuff_with_key_name2_content(serde_json::from_reader(contents).unwrap()),
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    });
    custom_object
}
```

Comment: Please check [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423) and a recent duplicate of it [How can I call `and_then` on a boxed Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50822267/155423). chances are very good that your version of futures isn't the version of futures that rusoto is using. Use `futures = "0.1"` instead.

Comment: It was the version. Setting it to 0.1 fixed that.