# Setting trait bounds on objects created within a function

Tags: generics, rust, traits, serde

I'm fooling around with the [ipc-channel](https://github.com/servo/ipc-channel) crate,  trying to build a generic struct that holds an `IpcOneShotServer`:

```
extern crate ipc_channel;
extern crate serde;

use ipc_channel::{ipc, Error};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

struct Supervisor<T> {
    server: ipc::IpcOneShotServer<T>,
}

impl<T> Supervisor<T>
where
    T: for<'de> Deserialize<'de> + Serialize,
{
    fn new() -> Result<Supervisor<T>, Error> {
        let (server, _) = ipc::IpcOneShotServer::new()?;
        Ok(Supervisor { server: server })
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following errors

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'de> T: serde::de::Deserialize<'de>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:67:27
   |
67 |         let (server, _) = ipc::IpcOneShotServer::new()?;
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'de> serde::de::Deserialize<'de>` is not implemented for `T`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where for<'de> T: serde::de::Deserialize<'de>` bound
   = note: required by `<ipc_channel::ipc::IpcOneShotServer<T>>::new`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: serde::ser::Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:67:27
   |
67 |         let (server, _) = ipc::IpcOneShotServer::new()?;
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::ser::Serialize` is not implemented for `T`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where T: serde::ser::Serialize` bound
   = note: required by `<ipc_channel::ipc::IpcOneShotServer<T>>::new`
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I have bounded the trait `T` by both `Deserialize` and `Serialize`. I thought that by binding the trait in the impl by those two other traits this would tell the type checker that as long as a `Supervisor` of type `T` implements `Deserialize` and `Serialize` it's safe to call `ipc::IpcOneShotServer::new()`.

Comment: This compile fine for me on rust 1.26.2

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423) but since we cannot reproduce the error, this is off topic as is.