# How do I use async/await syntax with Tokio?

Tags: async-await, rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to use async/await with processes in Rust. I'm using `tokio` and `tokio-process`:

```
#![feature(await_macro, async_await, futures_api)]

extern crate tokio;
extern crate tokio_process;

use std::process::Command;
use tokio_process::CommandExt;

fn main() {
    tokio::run_async(main_async());
}

async fn main_async() {
    let out = Command::new("echo")
        .arg("hello")
        .arg("world")
        .output_async();
    let s = await!(out);
}
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `tokio_process::OutputAsync: std::future::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:21:13
   |
21 |     let s = await!(out);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::future::Future` is not implemented for `tokio_process::OutputAsync`
   |
   = note: required by `std::future::poll_with_tls_waker`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `tokio_process::OutputAsync: std::future::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:21:13
   |
21 |     let s = await!(out);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::future::Future` is not implemented for `tokio_process::OutputAsync`
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

How do I get this right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: Use Tokio 0.2 or newer and it should just work.

Tokio 0.1 and related crates are implemented using the futures 0.1 crate. The `Future` trait from this crate is conceptually similar to the version of the `Future` trait from the standard library but substantially different in details. `async` / `await` syntax is built around the version of the trait in the standard library.

Tokio 0.2 and related crates are implemented using the standard library `Future` and have been reworked to better support `async` / `await` syntax.

## Tokio 0.2

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
```

```
use tokio::process::Command;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let out = Command::new("echo")
        .arg("hello")
        .arg("world")
        .output()
        .await?;

    let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(&out.stdout);

    println!("{}", s);
    Ok(())
}
```

```
$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.05s
     Running `target/debug/tokio2`
hello world
```

Tested with:

- Rustc 1.39.0

## Tokio 0.1

You have to [translate between a `Future` implemented against the trait from the futures 0.1 crate and from the standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58611380/155423). In addition, you need to start up the Tokio runtime services, ideally for both Tokio 0.1 and Tokio 0.3. That's where [tokio-compat](https://docs.rs/tokio-compat/0.1/tokio_compat/index.html) comes in:

```
[dependencies]
futures = { version = "0.3", features = ["compat"] }
tokio-compat = "0.1"
tokio-process = "0.2"
```

```
use futures::compat::Future01CompatExt;
use std::process::Command;
use tokio_process::CommandExt;

fn main() {
    tokio_compat::run_std(main_async());
}

async fn main_async() {
    let out = Command::new("echo")
        .arg("hello")
        .arg("world")
        .output_async();

    // Convert future from 0.1 to 0.3
    let s = out.compat().await;

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

```
% cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.07s
     Running `target/debug/tt`
Ok(Output { status: ExitStatus(ExitStatus(0)), stdout: "hello world\n", stderr: "" })
```

Tested with Rust 1.43.0

See also:

- [How do I convert an async / standard library future to futures 0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57785707/155423)
- [Is there a way that we can convert from futures 0.1 to the standard library futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58611380/155423)
- [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423)

Comment: when i use tokio v0.1.22 reqwest v0.10.0-alpha.2
tokio::run({   async fn   reqwest::get(url).await
got Error(Connect, Custom { kind: Other, error: "no current reactor" })

Comment: @CSQGB reqwest alpha [requires tokio alpha](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/v0.10.0-alpha.2/Cargo.toml#L63).

Comment: Tokio 0.1 is incompatible with  reqwest alpha
unless I use tokio v0.2.0-alpha ,right?

Comment: Hello Shepmaster. tokio-process 0.3.0-alpha.2 is incompatible with reqwest 0.10.0-alpha.2
I got error: failed to select a version for `futures-core-preview`.