# Cannot convert to or from a Postgres value of type `uuid` when inserting into Postgres

Tags: postgresql, rust

Here is the code I use to insert data in a Postgres database using the `postgres` crate (not present on Rust Playground unfortunately):

With the following Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "suff-import"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["greg"]

[dependencies]
csv = "1"
postgres = "0.15"
uuid = "0.7"
```

File `main.rs`:

```rust
extern crate csv;
extern crate postgres;
extern crate uuid;

use uuid::Uuid;
use postgres::{Connection, TlsMode};
use std::error::Error;
use std::io;
use csv::StringRecord;

struct Stuff {
    stuff_id: Uuid,
    created_at: String,
    description: String,
    is_something: bool,
}

impl Stuff {
    fn from_string_record(record: StringRecord) -> Stuff {
        Stuff {
            stuff_id: Uuid::parse_str(record.get(0).unwrap()).unwrap(),
            created_at: record.get(1).unwrap().to_string(),
            description: record.get(2).unwrap().to_string(),
            is_something: record.get(3).unwrap().to_string().parse::<i32>().unwrap() == 2,
        }
    }
}

fn save_row(dbcon: &Connection, stuff: Stuff) -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    dbcon.execute(
        "insert into public.stuff (stuff_id, created_at, description, is_something) values ($1::uuid, $2, $3, $4)",
        &[&format!("{}", &stuff.stuff_id).as_str(), &stuff.created_at, &stuff.description, &stuff.is_something]
    )?;
    Ok(())
}


fn import() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_reader(io::stdin());
    let dbcon = Connection::connect("postgres://gregoire@10.129.198.251/gregoire", TlsMode::None).unwrap();

    for result in reader.records() {
        let record = result?;
        println!(".");
        save_row(&dbcon, Stuff::from_string_record(record))?;
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(error) = import() {
        println!("There were some errors: {}", error);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

The program compiles, but it exits when run with the error message:

```
./target/debug/suff-import <<EOF
stuff_id,created_at,description,is_something
5252fff5-d04f-4e0f-8d3e-27da489cf40c,"2019-03-15 16:39:32","This is a description",1
EOF
.
There were some errors: type conversion error: cannot convert to or from a Postgres value of type `uuid`
```

I tested turning the UUID into a `&str` with the `format!` macro as Postgres should implicitly do the conversion to UUID, but it did not work (same error message). I then added an explicit `$1::uuid` in the Postgres query but the problem still occurs.

Comment: I'd say, either use `$1::uuid` and `&stuff.stuff_id` (no conversion to `&str`) or use `$1` (no `::uuid`) and `&format!("{}", &stuff.stuff_id).as_str()`. As is you're telling postgres to expect a UUID object, but you're passing a string…

Comment: @Jmb, the `$1::uuid` is a cast operator on the first argument, if the first argument is a string, it will be cast into a `uuid`. On the rust part, the array used to pass query parameters is an array of `&str`. I will follow @shepmaster instruction to provide a better question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [crate page](https://crates.io/crates/postgres) states:

> ### Optional features
>
> #### UUID type
>
> UUID support is provided optionally by the `with-uuid` feature, which adds `ToSql` and `FromSql` implementations for `uuid`'s `Uuid` type. Requires `uuid` version 0.5.

You haven't specified the feature, and you are using an incompatible version of uuid.

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "repro"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
postgres = { version = "0.15.2", features = ["with-uuid"] }
uuid = "0.5"
```

**Database setup**

```sql
CREATE TABLE junk (id uuid);
```

**Code**

```rust
use postgres::{Connection, TlsMode};
use std::error::Error;
use uuid::Uuid;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let conn = Connection::connect(
        "postgresql://shep@localhost:5432/stackoverflow",
        TlsMode::None,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let stuff_id = Uuid::default();

    conn.execute(
        "insert into public.junk (id) values ($1)",
        &[&stuff_id],
    )?;

    Ok(())
}
```

See also:

- [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423)