# the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to create a struct that I can use in diesel for insertion. Specifically I am making the struct Insertable. On compile I get this error.

I have a struct that I am trying to make `Insertable` via the derive attribute. I have a field called `Bounty` which is supposed to represent money, so I'm using `BigDecimal` as the type. Upon compilation, I get the error in the title. I've also tried using `f64` but that gives the same error.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
extern crate bigdecimal;

mod schema {
    use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
    table! {
        Threads (Id) {
            Id -> Int8,
            Views -> Int4,
            Points -> Int4,
            FlagPoints -> Int4,
            IsDisabled -> Bool,
            IsAnswered -> Bool,
            Bounty -> Numeric,
            Title -> Varchar,
            Body -> Text,
            UserId -> Int8,
            CreatedBy -> Varchar,
            CreatedOn -> Timestamptz,
            LastModifiedBy -> Varchar,
            LastModifiedOn -> Timestamptz,
        }
    }

    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
    #[table_name = "Threads"]
    pub struct InsertableThread { 
        pub Bounty: BigDecimal,
        pub Title: String,
        pub Body: String,
        pub UserId: i64
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I have my struct inside it's own file and this is the entire code. The struct `Thread` compiles without issue. The error happens on `InsertableThread` as it is the one using `BigDecimal`. This is the error that results.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `bigdecimal::BigDecimal: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:29:21
   |
29 |     #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>` for `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `bigdecimal::BigDecimal: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:29:21
   |
29 |     #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Expression` for `&bigdecimal::BigDecimal`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>` for `&bigdecimal::BigDecimal`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `bigdecimal::BigDecimal: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:29:21
   |
29 |     #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Expression` for `&'insert bigdecimal::BigDecimal`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>` for `&'insert bigdecimal::BigDecimal`
```

I am using Rust 1.34, diesel 1.4.2 and Postgres 11.

I am willing to change the types either in the database, Postgres, or in the Rust code. The database uses `numeric` and in the Rust code I've tried both `f64` and `BigDecimal`. I am also willing to implement the trait directly myself, but I need some guidance on how to do that as I could not find samples.

Comment: What purpose does providing the struct `Thread` serve? Is it *required* to reproduce the error? Please ensure your [MCVE] is **minimal**.

Comment: Please also attempt to format your question in a readable manner. The editor provides UI buttons to help you format it correctly, there is [a help document](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you are unfamiliar with Markdown, you can look at the existing edits that have been made to your question, and there's a live preview so you know what you are going to submit.

Comment: The code you have provided does not report the error you are asking about. Instead: *The attribute `table_name` is currently unknown to the compiler and may have meaning added to it in the future*. Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. Try to reproduce your error in a **brand new Cargo project**. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) and [Diesel tips](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust-diesel/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: Is it **required** to include all of those dependencies, such as "sparkpost", to produce the error? Are the fields `Title`, `Bounty`, etc **required**? Please ensure your [MCVE] is **minimal**.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Diesel uses [Cargo features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section) to opt-in to enhanced functionality.

I haven't found a clear documentation page for these, but they are listed in [its Cargo.toml](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/v1.4.2/diesel/Cargo.toml):

```
[features]
default = ["with-deprecated", "32-column-tables"]
extras = ["chrono", "serde_json", "uuid", "deprecated-time", "network-address", "numeric", "r2d2"]
unstable = ["diesel_derives/nightly"]
large-tables = ["32-column-tables"]
huge-tables = ["64-column-tables"]
x32-column-tables = ["32-column-tables"]
32-column-tables = []
x64-column-tables = ["64-column-tables"]
64-column-tables = ["32-column-tables"]
x128-column-tables = ["128-column-tables"]
128-column-tables = ["64-column-tables"]
postgres = ["pq-sys", "bitflags", "diesel_derives/postgres"]
sqlite = ["libsqlite3-sys", "diesel_derives/sqlite"]
mysql = ["mysqlclient-sys", "url", "diesel_derives/mysql"]
with-deprecated = []
deprecated-time = ["time"]
network-address = ["ipnetwork", "libc"]
numeric = ["num-bigint", "bigdecimal", "num-traits", "num-integer"]
```

You need to enable the **numeric** feature and ensure you use a version of bigdecimal that is compatible with Diesel:

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.2", features = ["numeric"] }
bigdecimal = "0.0.14"
```

And the code compiles:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use crate::schema::threads;
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;

mod schema {
    table! {
        threads (id) {
            id -> Int4,
            bounty -> Numeric,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
#[table_name = "threads"]
pub struct InsertableThread {
    pub bounty: BigDecimal,
}
```

See also:

- [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423)

Comment: Thank you Shepmaster. A small aside, I had to downgrade my BigDecimal version to 0.0.14. Does diesel have compatibility versions listings or the like for external crate dependencies such as this?

Comment: @user583824 that's why I provided the "see also" link, which is how I figured it out.

Comment: If you are coming to this question with a similar problem but other types, also check the "extras" feature. I just spent two hours trying to figure out why my Date/NaiveDate would not work.

Comment: For getting the compatible version of BigDecimal, just use `cargo tree`

Comment: You can check the required bigdecimal version by doing this: `cargo tree | grep bigdecimal`

Answer (score 10):

In addition to adding the `"numeric"` feature flag. Diesel supports a range of bigdecimal versions:

- v1.4.8 supports `bigdecimal >=0.0.10, <0.2.0`
- v2.0.4 supports `bigdecimal >=0.0.13, <0.4.0`

However, the version of bigdecimal you use in your crate must be compatible with what Diesel is using as its version of bigdecimal. Otherwise you may get the error above.

You can get the version used by Diesel by using `cargo tree`. Example command and output:

```
> cargo tree -p diesel --depth=1
diesel v1.4.8
├── bigdecimal v0.1.2 <-----------------
├── bitflags v1.3.2
├── byteorder v1.4.3
...
```

Based on that output above, your `Cargo.toml` should look like so:

```toml
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.8", features = ["numeric", ...] }
bigdecimal = "0.1.2" # <-----------------
```

Comment: This in combination with https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/1879#issuecomment-450288337

resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

You might reach this question by searching an error message that is really similar:

```
the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `(schema::..., schema::..., schema::...)`
```

This is just a reminder to count the number of columns you have in the `table!{}` macro because you might be reaching the default 32 column limit.

According to the [Diesel changelog](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#121---2018-04-11) you should use the following features if you use more than the **default 32 columns**.

## 64 columns (**Cargo.toml**)

```toml
diesel = { version = "1.4", features = [..., "64-column-tables"] }
```

## 128 columns (**Cargo.toml**):

```toml
diesel = { version = "1.4", features = [..., "128-column-tables"] }
```

Using more columns is not possible and might be a hint that the table design is not ideal (See: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/2312#issuecomment-591623303).

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question, which is about `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`?

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the comment. I added an explanation. When searching error messages it is really easy to end up on this page not having noticed that the error message is slightly different.

Comment: I exactly came to this question because I reached 33 columns and should tell that given the verbosity of the error, here is my +1^32 for you.

Comment: this is exactly what happened to me. Thank you.