# Use derive Insertable for float

Tags: sql, rust, rust-diesel

I started with diesel and rocket in Rust and have a problem with inserting floating values to the database.
My struct looks like:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Insertable)]
#[table_name = "database"]
pub struct New_Data{
    pub data1: f64,
    pub data2: f64,
    pub data3: f64,
}
```

and I get this error: the trait bound `f64: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
label: the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `f64`, 
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>` for `f64`

I've read that diesel kinda uses its own data/SQL types but I have no idea how to declare a Float.
I also tried to use diesel::sql_types::Float with a similar error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the trait \`diesel::Expression\` is not implemented for \`bigdecimal::BigDecimal\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783064/the-trait-dieselexpression-is-not-implemented-for-bigdecimalbigdecimal)

Comment: Just realized my mistake was in the database (schema.rs). Just had the whole time the wrong type in my database and didn't notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a mismatch between the schema type of the field, as defined in the diesel auto-generated `schema.rs`, and the type of the field you defined in `New_Data`. Look inside the auto-generated schema for a `data1 ->` definition, you may find something like:

```
data1 -> Float4
```

In this case the type of the field needs to be `f32`. Otherwise, if it's `Float8`, then the type should be `f64`. This mapping between the language of diesel schema types extends further to Option and Nullable. If it appears as `Nullable<Float4>` in the schema, then it should be `Option<f32>` in the type.

Comment: Ah got it. My mistake was in the migration up.sql. I put the wrong type in there. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @Jojo - Could you share your CREATE TABLE sql with the float columns? I have tried various attempts with `FLOAT`, `DOUBLE` or even `DECIMAL`, but all fail.