# Parse data into Vec<T> and insert vector into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, rust, serde, rust-diesel

I am receiving a JSON array which is inserted into a `Vec<T>`. I am using serde for the parsing. I want to insert the vector to a database table. The JSON array is parsed fine. The field `publication_time` is with time zone so I parse it using `my_date_format` using the [example](https://serde.rs/custom-date-format.html) provided by serde. When I add (derive) `Insertable` to the struct `cargo build` fails with

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `DateTime<Local>: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
 --> src/models.rs:5:23
  |
5 | #[derive(Deserialize, Insertable)]
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `DateTime<Local>`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamp>>` for `DateTime<Local>`
  = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

models.rs:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize};
use chrono::{DateTime, Local};
use crate::schema::readings;

#[derive(Deserialize, Insertable)]
struct Reading {
    #[serde(with = "my_date_format")]
    publication_time: DateTime<Local>,
    id: i32,
    index: i32,
    field_description: String,
    measurement: f32,
}
```

schema.rs:

```rust
table! {
    readings {
        measurement_time_default -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
        id -> Nullable<Integer>,
        index -> Nullable<Integer>,
        field_description -> Nullable<Text>,
        measurement -> Nullable<Float>,
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
serde = "1"
serde_json = "1"
serde-datetime = "0.1.0"
diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["postgres", "chrono"] }
chrono = "0.4.19"
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783064/the-trait-dieselexpression-is-not-implemented-for-bigdecimalbigdecimal) similar question regarding `BigDecimal`, but my issue is with `DateTime<Local>`. I have used `chrono::NaiveDateTime` in another project where I also insert data to a table. In this answer there is [linked](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/v1.4.4/diesel/Cargo.toml) to the particular versions diesel is using. When I change the type to `NaiveDateTime` serde fails to compile with this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/models.rs:5:10
  |
5 | #[derive(Deserialize, Insertable)]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `NaiveDateTime`, found struct `DateTime`
  |
  = note: expected struct `NaiveDateTime`
             found struct `DateTime<Local>`
  = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: This question is missing crucial details to provide a complete answer. Please add the corresponding schema definition and your implementation of `my_date_format`.
Otherwise it's only possible to say that `DateTime<Local>` is not compatible with any diesel sql type, therefore you cannot just use that type as part of your `Insertable` derive.

Comment: Thank you @weiznich. You solved it. I've edited the question and added schema.rs. Then I performed a new search and saw https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/types/sql_types/struct.Timestamptz.html where it uses Timestamptz. I've added the original Timestamp for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by weiznich to include schema.rs pointed me in the right direction. I changed Timestamp to Timestamptz.

schema.rs:

```
table! {
    readings {
        measurement_time_default -> Nullable<Timestamptz>,
        id -> Nullable<Integer>,
        index -> Nullable<Integer>,
        field_description -> Nullable<Text>,
        measurement -> Nullable<Float>,
    }
}
```

Timestamptz uses DateTime as described [here](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/types/sql_types/struct.Timestamptz.html). Timestamp uses NaiveDateTime. This solves my issue.