# How to retrieve the underlying error from a Failure Error?

Tags: error-handling, rust

When trying to open a broken epub/ZIP file with epub-rs, the zip-rs crate error (which doesn't use Failure) is wrapped into a `failure::Error` by epub-rs. I want to handle each error type of zip-rs with an distinct error handler and need a way to match against the underlying error. How can I retrieve it from Failure?

```
fn main() {
    match epub::doc::EpubDoc::new("a.epub") {
        Ok(epub) => // do something with the epub
        Err(error) => {
            // handle errors
        }
    }
}
```

`error.downcast::<zip::result::ZipError>()` fails and `error.downcast_ref()` returns None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can downcast from a Failure [`Error`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/struct.Error.html) into another type that implements [`Fail`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/trait.Fail.html) by using one of three functions:

- [`downcast`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/struct.Error.html#method.downcast)
- [`downcast_ref`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/struct.Error.html#method.downcast_ref)
- [`downcast_mut`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/struct.Error.html#method.downcast_mut)

```
use failure; // 0.1.5
use std::{fs, io};

fn generate() -> Result<(), failure::Error> {
    fs::read_to_string("/this/does/not/exist")?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    match generate() {
        Ok(_) => panic!("Should have an error"),
        Err(e) => match e.downcast_ref::<io::Error>() {
            Some(e) => println!("Got an io::Error: {}", e),
            None => panic!("Could not downcast"),
        },
    }
}
```

---

For your specific case, I'm guessing that you are either running into mismatched dependency versions (see [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423) for examples and techniques on how to track this down) or that you simply are getting the wrong error type. For example, a missing file is actually an `std::io::Error`:

```
// epub = "1.2.0"
// zip = "0.4.2"
// failure = "0.1.5"

use std::io;

fn main() {
    if let Err(error) = epub::doc::EpubDoc::new("a.epub") {
        match error.downcast_ref::<io::Error>() {
            Some(i) => println!("IO error: {}", i),
            None => {
                panic!("Other error: {} {:?}", error, error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  my depency versions were different.