# How to have multiple incompatible versions of the same indirect dependency?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use `actix-web` and `reqwest` crates in the same project, but they depend on different versions of `tokio`.

Apparently, Cargo can't select a version of `tokio` which would satisfy all direct dependencies, but I'm not even using those dependencies in the same context:

- `actix-web` is for server REST API implementation
- `reqwest` is for system tests only

---

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "test-cargo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
actix-rt = "1.0.0"
actix-web = "2.0.0-alpha.6"

[dev-dependencies]
reqwest = "0.10.0-alpha.2"
```

Output of `cargo build`:

```
Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for `tokio`.
    ... required by package `reqwest v0.10.0-alpha.2`
    ... which is depended on by `test-cargo v0.1.0 (/workspaces/test-cargo)`
versions that meet the requirements `= 0.2.0-alpha.6` are: 0.2.0-alpha.6

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `tokio v0.2.4`
    ... which is depended on by `actix-rt v1.0.0`
    ... which is depended on by `actix-web v2.0.0-alpha.6`
    ... which is depended on by `test-cargo v0.1.0 (/workspaces/test-cargo)`

failed to select a version for `tokio` which could resolve this conflict
```

---

I've thought of some workarounds, but they are all unacceptable:

- downgrade one of the direct dependencies so that `tokio` versions would match — then my dependencies are not the versions I want.
- replace `reqwest` with a similar crate which doesn't depend on `tokio` — then my dependencies are not the crates I want.
- move tests with `reqwest` to a separate package

Comment: In general, Cargo handles this fine (see [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423)). The problem is that the resolver has some issues with the prerelease version of crates.

Comment: For your *specific* issue and crates, you can depend on the `reqwest` crate's master branch instead of a released version, or downgrade to `reqwest` 0.9, which will pull in `tokio` 0.1 (and you'll have `tokio` 0.2 for your main app).

Comment: @Shepmaster I've tried to use stable version of `reqwest` and yeah it works. Do we have issue in cargo repository for that?..

Comment: So, cargo can match `tokio` versions `0.2.4` - `0.1.7`, but not `0.2.4` - `=0.2.0-alpha.6`. Probably because of `=`?.

Comment: @Shepmaster Are you sure cargo cannot match `tokio` versions because one of them is prerelease `-alpha.6`? Because I still can add `0.2.0-alpha.6`, but not `=0.2.0-alpha.6`, so I believe issue in that strict version sign `=`. Let's update title to more general: "How to have multiple *incompatible* versions of the same indirect dependency?"