# Why do I get the error "there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of Tokio runtime" even though I have #[tokio::main]?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm following [the mdns Rust documentation](https://docs.rs/mdns/1.1.0/mdns/) and pasted the example code but it throws the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of Tokio runtime'
```

Here's the code that I have:

```rust
use futures_util::{pin_mut, stream::StreamExt};
use mdns::{Error, Record, RecordKind};
use std::{net::IpAddr, time::Duration};

const SERVICE_NAME: &'static str = "_googlecast._tcp.local";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    // Iterate through responses from each Cast device, asking for new devices every 15s
    let stream = mdns::discover::all(SERVICE_NAME, Duration::from_secs(15))?.listen();
    pin_mut!(stream);

    while let Some(Ok(response)) = stream.next().await {
        let addr = response.records().filter_map(self::to_ip_addr).next();

        if let Some(addr) = addr {
            println!("found cast device at {}", addr);
        } else {
            println!("cast device does not advertise address");
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn to_ip_addr(record: &Record) -> Option<IpAddr> {
    match record.kind {
        RecordKind::A(addr) => Some(addr.into()),
        RecordKind::AAAA(addr) => Some(addr.into()),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
mdns = "1.1.0"
futures-util = "0.3.8"
tokio = { version = "0.3.3", features = ["full"] }
```

What am I missing? I tried looking online but haven't found how to create a reactor for this use case.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are using a newer version of Tokio, such as 0.3 or 1.x, and many packages, including mdns 1.1.0, rely on an older version of Tokio, such as 0.2.

```
% cargo tree -d
tokio v0.2.22
└── mdns v1.1.0
    └── example_project v0.1.0

tokio v0.3.3
└── example_project v0.1.0
```

For now, you will need to match versions of the Tokio runtime. The easiest way is to use Tokio 0.2 yourself. The [tokio-compat-02](https://github.com/LucioFranco/tokio-compat-02) crate may also be useful in some cases.

See also:

- [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423)

---

Various error messages with the same root cause:

> there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime

> there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of Tokio runtime

> not currently running on the Tokio runtime

Answer (score 13):

Fix for me was adding this to `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
async-std = { version = "1", features = ["attributes", "tokio1"] }
```

https://github.com/ATiltedTree/ytextract/issues/25

Answer (score 9):

At the time of writing, a fair amount of crates are already using Tokio v1, but others might still be under an experimental phase. Check your crates for *prerelease versions* which might have already upgraded their tokio runtime compatibility.

A relevant example of this was `actix-web`, which uses runtime 1.0 of Tokio since version 4. Although there were prereleases of this major increment since 2022-01-07, version 4.0.0 was only released in 2022-02-25.

```ini
actix-web = { version = "4.0.0-beta.10" }
```

Comment: Thanks. I had this error exactly in actix-web and was about to dissappointingly downgrade my tokio to 0.2. I prefer less stable beta over too old <1 versions. :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm using tokio v1.34.0, adding `#[tokio::main]` solved the problem:

```
#[launch]
#[tokio::main]
async fn rocket() -> _ {
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran the same code that produced the error with only changes to the dependencies.

```
[dependencies]
mdns = "3.0.0"
futures-util = "0.3.28"
tokio = { version = "1.32.0", features 
  = ["full"] }
    
    use futures_util::{pin_mut, 
      stream::StreamExt};
    use mdns::{Error, Record, 
      RecordKind};
    use std::{net::IpAddr, 
      time::Duration};
    
    const SERVICE_NAME: &'static str = 
      "_googlecast._tcp.local";
    
    #[tokio::main]
    async fn main() -> Result<(), 
      Error> {
        // Iterate through responses from 
        // each Cast device, asking for new 
        // devices every 15s
        let stream = 
          mdns::discover::all(SERVICE_NAME, 
          Duration::from_secs(15))?.listen();
        pin_mut!(stream);
    
        while let Some(Ok(response)) = 
          stream.next().await 
        {
            let addr = 
            response.records().filter_map(  
              self::to_ip_addr).next();
    
            if let Some(addr) = addr {
                println!("found cast device 
                  at {}", addr);
            } else {
                println!("cast device does 
                  not advertise address");
            }
        }
    
        Ok(())
    }
    
    fn to_ip_addr(record: &Record) -> 
        Option<IpAddr> {
        match record.kind {
            RecordKind::A(addr) => 
              Some(addr.into()),
            RecordKind::AAAA(addr) => 
              Some(addr.into()),
            _ => None,
        }
    }

// A small sample of the output I 
// received without error is below:

found cast device at 10.0.0.165
found cast device at 10.0.0.171
found cast device at 10.0.0.158
```

Comment: This answer needs to provide more supporting information and something new/unique that the other answers don't provide.

Comment: The following code is the same as the person receiving the following error:

Comment: I added more substance to my original submittal.  Hope this helps.