# rust AWS multipart upload using rusoto, multithreaded (rayon) panicked at 'there is no reactor running ...`

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, rust, rayon, rusoto

I'm trying to upload a file to `aws` in `rust`, for that I'm using the s3 rust client by [`rusoto_s3`](https://crates.io/crates/rusoto_s3), I managed to get the multipart upload code working when these parts are sent from a **single** thread, however, that is not what I want, I want to upload big files and I want to be able to send these parts in **multiple** threads, for that, I did a little bit of googling and I came across [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/).

For info the way multipart upload works is as follows:

1. Initiate the multipart -> aws will return an ID
2. Use this ID to send the different parts, pass the file chunk, and the part number -> aws will return an `Etag`
3. Once you sent all the parts, send a complete upload request with all the completed parts as an array contains the `Etag` and the part number.

I'm new to rust, coming from C++ and Java background, here is my code:

```
#[tokio::test]
async fn if_multipart_then_upload_multiparts_dicom() {
    let now = Instant::now();
    dotenv().ok();
    let local_filename = "./files/test_big.DCM";
    let destination_filename = "24_time_test.dcm";

    let mut file = std::fs::File::open(local_filename).unwrap();
    const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 7_000_000;
    let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(CHUNK_SIZE);

    let client = super::get_client().await;
    let create_multipart_request = CreateMultipartUploadRequest {
        bucket: client.bucket_name.to_owned(),
        key: destination_filename.to_owned(),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    // Start the multipart upload and note the upload_id generated
    let response = client
        .s3
        .create_multipart_upload(create_multipart_request)
        .await
        .expect("Couldn't create multipart upload");
    let upload_id = response.upload_id.unwrap();

    // Create upload parts
    let create_upload_part = |body: Vec<u8>, part_number: i64| -> UploadPartRequest {
        UploadPartRequest {
            body: Some(body.into()),
            bucket: client.bucket_name.to_owned(),
            key: destination_filename.to_owned(),
            upload_id: upload_id.to_owned(),
            part_number: part_number,
            ..Default::default()
        }
    };

    let completed_parts = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));

    rayon::scope(|scope| {
        let mut part_number = 1;
        loop {
            let maximum_bytes_to_read = CHUNK_SIZE - buffer.len();
            println!("maximum_bytes_to_read: {}", maximum_bytes_to_read);
            file.by_ref()
                .take(maximum_bytes_to_read as u64)
                .read_to_end(&mut buffer)
                .unwrap();

            println!("length: {}", buffer.len());
            println!("part_number: {}", part_number);
            if buffer.len() == 0 {
                // The file has ended.
                break;
            }

            let next_buffer = Vec::with_capacity(CHUNK_SIZE);
            let data_to_send = buffer;
            let completed_parts_cloned = completed_parts.clone();
            scope.spawn(move |_| {
                let part = create_upload_part(data_to_send.to_vec(), part_number);
                {
                    let part_number = part.part_number;
                    let client = executor::block_on(super::get_client());
                    let response = executor::block_on(client.s3.upload_part(part));

                    completed_parts_cloned.lock().unwrap().push(CompletedPart {
                        e_tag: response
                            .expect("Couldn't complete multipart upload")
                            .e_tag
                            .clone(),
                        part_number: Some(part_number),
                    });
                }
            });

            buffer = next_buffer;
            part_number = part_number + 1;
        }
    });

    let completed_upload = CompletedMultipartUpload {
        parts: Some(completed_parts.lock().unwrap().to_vec()),
    };

    let complete_req = CompleteMultipartUploadRequest {
        bucket: client.bucket_name.to_owned(),
        key: destination_filename.to_owned(),
        upload_id: upload_id.to_owned(),
        multipart_upload: Some(completed_upload),
        ..Default::default()
    };
    client
        .s3
        .complete_multipart_upload(complete_req)
        .await
        .expect("Couldn't complete multipart upload");
    println!(
        "time taken: {}, with chunk:: {}",
        now.elapsed().as_secs(),
        CHUNK_SIZE
    );
}
```

here is a sample of the output and error I'm getting:

```
maximum_bytes_to_read: 7000000
length: 7000000
part_number: 1
maximum_bytes_to_read: 7000000
length: 7000000
part_number: 2
maximum_bytes_to_read: 7000000
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime', C:\Users\DNDT\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-1.2.0\src\runtime\blocking\pool.rs:85:33
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime', C:\Users\DNDT\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-1.2.0\src\runtime\blocking\pool.rs:85:33
length: 7000000
```

I googled this error but I did not have a clear understanding on what actually its:

```
there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of Tokio runtime”
```

Here is what I found:
[another question with the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64779920/why-do-i-get-the-error-there-is-no-reactor-running-must-be-called-from-the-con)

[and another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763102/panic-with-thread-main-panicked-at-not-currently-running-on-the-tokio-runtim)

Which seems its some compatibility issue because s3 might be using some version of `tokio` that is not compatible with the version of tokio I have.

Here are some relevant dependencies:

```
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
tokio-compat-02 = "0.1.2"
rusoto_s3 = "0.46.0"
rusoto_core = "0.46.0"
rusoto_credential = "0.46.0"
rayon = "1.5.0"
```

I think the main issue comes on actually wanting to run `async` code in a `rayon` thread. I tried changing my `async` code to blocking code using `executor::block_on`, I also spend some time trying to make the compiler happy, I have multiple threads they all want to write to `let completed_parts = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));` so I did some cloning here to make the complier happy.

Also if my used craes matter, here are they:

```
extern crate dotenv;
extern crate tokio;
use bytes::Bytes;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use futures::executor;
use futures::*;
use rusoto_core::credential::{EnvironmentProvider, ProvideAwsCredentials};
use rusoto_s3::util::{PreSignedRequest, PreSignedRequestOption};
use rusoto_s3::PutObjectRequest;
use rusoto_s3::StreamingBody;
use rusoto_s3::{
    CompleteMultipartUploadRequest, CompletedMultipartUpload, CompletedPart,
    CreateMultipartUploadRequest, UploadPartRequest, S3,
};

use std::io::Read;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::time::Instant;
use tokio::fs;
```

New to rust, so there a lot of moving pieces to get this one right!

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple threads? In this kind of situation, the bottleneck is usually network bandwidth (or the TCP window), _not_ CPU power, so multithreading will not improve upload speed.

Comment: And if you want to upload using multiple parallel connections, then you can spawn several tokio tasks and let tokio handle the parallelism.

Comment: I had a similar discussion with a collogue of mine, actually I want to try things out as AWS mention that it would improve throughput by uploading parts in parallel: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html @Jmb

Comment: Uploading parts in parallel does _not_ mean using multiple threads but multiple connections. Since connections are asynchronous you should just [`spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.3.0/tokio/fn.spawn.html) async functions for each file part then `await` them all. Let Tokio handle the parallelism (which may use threads or not but _will_ send the parts in parallel either way).

Comment: Yup thanks for the direction, I managed to do just that. @Jmb

Comment: The file takes half of the time now to upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Jmb for the discussion, I got rid of the threads and I `spawn` a `tokio` task as follows:

create a vector to hold or the futures so we could wait for them:

```
let mut multiple_parts_futures = Vec::new();
```

spawn the `async` task:

```
loop { // loop file chuncks
    ...
    let send_part_task_future = tokio::task::spawn(async move {
    // Upload part
    ...
}
```

and then later wait for all futures:

```
let _results = futures::future::join_all(multiple_parts_futures).await;
```

worth mentioning, the completed parts need to be sorted:

```
let mut completed_parts_vector = completed_parts.lock().unwrap().to_vec();
completed_parts_vector.sort_by_key(|part| part.part_number);
```

The whole code is:

```
#[tokio::test]
async fn if_multipart_then_upload_multiparts_dicom() {
    let now = Instant::now();
    dotenv().ok();
    let local_filename = "./files/test_big.DCM";
    let destination_filename = generate_unique_name();
    let destination_filename_clone = destination_filename.clone();
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open(local_filename).unwrap();
    const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 6_000_000;
    let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(CHUNK_SIZE);

    let client = super::get_client().await;
    let create_multipart_request = CreateMultipartUploadRequest {
        bucket: client.bucket_name.to_owned(),
        key: destination_filename.to_owned(),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    // Start the multipart upload and note the upload_id generated
    let response = client
        .s3
        .create_multipart_upload(create_multipart_request)
        .await
        .expect("Couldn't create multipart upload");
    let upload_id = response.upload_id.unwrap();

    let upload_id_clone = upload_id.clone();
    // Create upload parts
    let create_upload_part = move |body: Vec<u8>, part_number: i64| -> UploadPartRequest {
        UploadPartRequest {
            body: Some(body.into()),
            bucket: client.bucket_name.to_owned(),
            key: destination_filename_clone.to_owned(),
            upload_id: upload_id_clone.to_owned(),
            part_number: part_number,
            ..Default::default()
        }
    };

    let create_upload_part_arc = Arc::new(create_upload_part);
    let completed_parts = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));

    let mut part_number = 1;

    let mut multiple_parts_futures = Vec::new();
    loop {
        let maximum_bytes_to_read = CHUNK_SIZE - buffer.len();
        println!("maximum_bytes_to_read: {}", maximum_bytes_to_read);
        file.by_ref()
            .take(maximum_bytes_to_read as u64)
            .read_to_end(&mut buffer)
            .unwrap();
        println!("length: {}", buffer.len());
        println!("part_number: {}", part_number);
        if buffer.len() == 0 {
            // The file has ended.
            break;
        }
        let next_buffer = Vec::with_capacity(CHUNK_SIZE);
        let data_to_send = buffer;
        let completed_parts_cloned = completed_parts.clone();
        let create_upload_part_arc_cloned = create_upload_part_arc.clone();
        let send_part_task_future = tokio::task::spawn(async move {
            let part = create_upload_part_arc_cloned(data_to_send.to_vec(), part_number);
            {
                let part_number = part.part_number;
                let client = super::get_client().await;
                let response = client.s3.upload_part(part).await;
                completed_parts_cloned.lock().unwrap().push(CompletedPart {
                    e_tag: response
                        .expect("Couldn't complete multipart upload")
                        .e_tag
                        .clone(),
                    part_number: Some(part_number),
                });
            }
        });
        multiple_parts_futures.push(send_part_task_future);
        buffer = next_buffer;
        part_number = part_number + 1;
    }
    let client = super::get_client().await;
    println!("waiting for futures");
    let _results = futures::future::join_all(multiple_parts_futures).await;

    let mut completed_parts_vector = completed_parts.lock().unwrap().to_vec();
    completed_parts_vector.sort_by_key(|part| part.part_number);
    println!("futures done");
    let completed_upload = CompletedMultipartUpload {
        parts: Some(completed_parts_vector),
    };

    let complete_req = CompleteMultipartUploadRequest {
        bucket: client.bucket_name.to_owned(),
        key: destination_filename.to_owned(),
        upload_id: upload_id.to_owned(),
        multipart_upload: Some(completed_upload),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    client
        .s3
        .complete_multipart_upload(complete_req)
        .await
        .expect("Couldn't complete multipart upload");
    println!(
        "time taken: {}, with chunk:: {}",
        now.elapsed().as_secs(),
        CHUNK_SIZE
    );
}
```