# How do I use rocket_contrib::Uuid in a form?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am using the 0.5.0-dev version of rocket and rocket_contrib. I want to use a `Uuid` in my form, but I get the following compilation error:

> the trait `FromFormField<'_>` is not implemented for `rocket_contrib::uuid::Uuid`

I do not understand this as according to the [docs](https://api.rocket.rs/master/rocket_contrib/uuid/struct.Uuid.html) `Uuid` implements `FromFormField`. What am I doing wrong?

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

use rocket::data::TempFile;
use rocket::form::{DataField, Form};
use rocket_contrib::uuid::Uuid;

#[derive(FromForm)]
struct FileUploadForm<'v> {
    id: Uuid,
    file: TempFile<'v>,
}

#[post("/upload", data = "<data>")]
fn upload(data: Form<FileUploadForm>) -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
    let id = "uuid".to_string();
    Ok(id)
}

fn rocket() -> rocket::Rocket {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![upload])
}

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    rocket().launch().await;
}
```

Comment: No, can be removed. I edited the question.

Comment: I must be stupid cause `error[E0583]: file not found for module `authentication``

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `Cargo.toml` was incorrect, I did not properly included `rocket_contrib`. The correct version would be the following

```
[package]
name = "stackoverflow"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket", version = "0.5.0-dev" }

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket"
version = "0.5.0-dev"
default-features = false
features = ["uuid"]
```